# GetMessage() while the thread is blocked in SwapBuffers()

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, opengl, message-queue

Vsync blocks SwapBuffers(), which is what I want. My problem is that, since input messages go to the same thread that owns the window, any messages that come in while SwapBuffers() is blocked won't be processed immediately, but only after the vsync triggers the buffer swap and SwapBuffers() returns. So I have all my compute threads sitting idle instead of processing the scene for rendering in the next frame using the most recent input. I'm particularly concerned with having very low latency. I need some way to access all pending input messages to the window from other threads.

Windows API provides a way to wait for either Windows events or input messages using MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(), yet there's no similar way to wait for a buffer swap together with other things. That's very unfortunate.

I considered calling SwapBuffers() in another thread, but that requires glFinish() to be called in the window's thread before signalling another thread to SwapBuffers(), and glFinish() is still a blocking call so it's not a good solution.

I considered hooking, but that also looks like a dead end. Hooking with WH_GETMESSAGE will have the GetMsgProc() be called not asynchronously, but when the window's thread calls GetMessage()/PeekMessage(), so it's no help. Installing a global hook doesn't help me either due to the need of calling RegisterTouchWindow() with a specific window handle to process WM_TOUCH -- and my input is touch. And, while for mouse and keyboard, you can install low level hooks that capture messages as they're posted to the thread's queue, rather than when the thread calls GetMessage()/PeekMessage(), there appears to be no similar option for touch.

I also looked at wglDelayBeforeSwapNV(), but I don't see what's preventing the OS from preempting a thread sometimes after the call to that function but before SwapBuffers(), causing a miss of the next vsync signal.

So what's a good workaround? Can I make a second, invisible window, that will somehow be always the active one and so get all input messages, while the visible one is displaying the rendering? According to another discussion, message-only windows (CreateWindow with HWND_MESSAGE) are not compatible with WM_TOUCH. Is there perhaps some undocumented event that SwapBuffers() is internally waiting on that I could access and feed to MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()? My target is a fixed platform (Windows 8.1 64-bit) so I'm fine with using undocumented functionality, should it exist. I do want to avoid writing my own touchscreen driver, however.

Answer (score 3):

Out of curiosity, why not implement your entire drawing logic in that other thread? It appears the problem you are running into is that the message pump is driven by the same thread that draws. Since Windows does not let you drive the message pump from a different thread than the one that created the window, the easiest solution would just be to push all the GL stuff into a different thread.

`SwapBuffers (...)` is also not necessarily going to block. As-per requirements of VSYNC an implementation need only block the *next command* that would modify the backbuffer while ***all*** backbuffers are pending a swap. Triple buffering changes things up a little bit by introducing a second backbuffer.

One possible implementation of triple buffering will discard the oldest backbuffer when it comes time to swap, thus `SwapBuffers (...)` would never cause blocking (this is effectively how modern versions of Windows work in ***windowed*** mode with the DWM enabled). Other implementations will eventually present both backbuffers, this *reduces* (but does not eliminate) blocking but also results in the display of late frames.

Unfortunately WGL does not let you request the number of backbuffers in a swap-chain (beyond **0** single-buffered or **1** double-buffered); the only way to get triple buffering on Windows is using driver settings. Lowest message latency will come from driving GL in a different thread, but triple buffering can help a little bit while requiring no effort on your part.

Comment: If I create the OpenGL context without a window, on another thread, I have no way of displaying it (unless I render offscreen then copy it to the window, which would obviously defeat the attempt to decrease latency). (Also, I am already using triple-buffering through the driver setting.)

Comment: When did multiple contexts enter the discussion? Did I miss something?

Comment: My mistake. The first sentence wasn't relevant so I've removed it.

Comment: You can easily draw from a different thread than the one you create your window in. All you have to do is relinquish the context from the thread that created the window/context by calling `wglMakeCurrent (NULL,NULL)`. Then once your worker thread for GL is started, you can make the appropriate `wglMakeCurrent (...)` call and do all GL commands from that thread. The Win32 message pump is actually the only place here where the thread that created the window is relevant and immutable, which is why I suggested moving GL into a separate thread.

Comment: I will try this method. I was not aware that I could make a GL context current on a non-window thread and it would keep displaying on the original window. Are there any performance implications? For example, is this likely to interact with driver optimizations (such as the threading optimization setting in the NVIDIA control panel), or perhaps the OS compositor? I'm not doing anything in terms of repainting messages other than simply calling ValidateRect() on WM_PAINT, so I can't think of anything that would affect GL as far as the message loop goes.

Comment: As long as you have all of your drawing in one thread the driver really does not care. If you started trying to be clever and doing multi-threaded rendering then things could get messy, you would need fence sync objects in order to guarantee the commands executed in the proper order. Also, as far as I know the "threading optimization" option refers to how the driver deals with CPU-intensive tasks (like submitting 24-bit RGB texture data - the driver usually has to convert that to 32-bit BGRA but it is usually not necessary that this conversion cause the calling thread to block).

Comment: Andon, there might be an issue here. From https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182226-SwapBuffers%28%29-in-another-thread I quote: "Nvidia told me this was because DeviceContexts are actually thread-affine, and GDI functions should only be called on them in the threads that created them. Quote from Nvidia 'Calling GDI functions using an HDC from the non-hdc-affine thread has always been wrong (OpenGL is a GDI api and GDI objects like HDCs are thread-affine), but the failure cases are in general hard to repro.'"

Comment: Hmm, that is news to me. I have been doing this in a particular piece of software I wrote 12 years ago without any issues. I wonder if it specific to a certain NV driver release?